# Avoid completing directory names when changing vim buffers

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a directory structure, such as

```
dir
├── foo
│   ├── bar.c
│   ├── bar.h
│   ├── foo.c
│   └── foo.h
└── config
    └── foo.conf
```

And I have each of the files in `foo/`, as well as `foo.conf` open in a vim buffer. If I want to switch to `foo.c`, I type `:b foo<TAB>`. However, since “foo” matches the name of the parent directory, vim suggests all the files in `foo/` as possible matches.

I would like only `foo.conf`,`foo.c` and `foo.h` to be suggested. Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
:b foo[^/]*$<Tab>
```